# Swift Autolayout - Height Anchor not being applied

Tags: ios, swift, ios-autolayout

I am working on a "Profile View Controller" which is inside a `TableViewCell` and table cell dimension is set as `UITableView.automaticDimension`: 
[image]

The problem is that I would like to set the background image view (Blue) with a variable height based on cell width and a 16:9 ratio. For some reason I am not being able to change the view height even if I set the constant.

Here the code:

```
let topView : UIView = {
   let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    view.backgroundColor = .yoofitDarkBlue
    view.layer.masksToBounds = true
    view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    view.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yoofitDarkBlue.cgColor
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 12.0
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
    return view
}()

let userImage : UIImageView = {
   let i = UIImageView()
    i.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    i.image = UIImage(named: "user2")
    i.layer.masksToBounds = true
    i.layer.cornerRadius = 75
    i.layer.borderWidth = 1
    i.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    return i
}()

var userNameLabel:UILabel = {
    let l = UILabel()
    l.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    l.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 20)
    l.textAlignment = .center
    l.textColor = .yoofitBlack
    return l
}()

func setupViews() {
    self.backgroundColor = .clear
    self.selectionStyle = .none
    addSubview(topView)
    let width = self.frame.width
    print(width) // print 320
    topView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    topView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    topView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant:  -8).isActive = true
    topView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width/16*9).isActive = true // this doesn't work even if I set another number like 600
    topView.layoutIfNeeded()
    addSubview(userImage)
    userImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    userImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    userImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    userImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    addSubview(userNameLabel)
    userNameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userImage.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    userNameLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userImage.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    userNameLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    userNameLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
    userNameLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PLEASE NOTE THERE ARE 2 answers to this question. The latter is definitely the correct one but the first maybe may help others.

So this is how I fixed it but I hope to get better answers. This answer helped me to go to the right path [(iOS: How to Align The Center of a View With The Bottom of Another View With AutoLayout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37371226/ios-how-to-align-the-center-of-a-view-with-the-bottom-of-another-view-with-auto)

1. I have added a containing view which is twice as the required size of my top view (the blue one).
2. I centered the picture on the containing view.

   ```
   self.conteiningView.backgroundColor = .red // I made this red so you can visually see how the views are related to each other
   let width = self.frame.width

   self.addSubview(conteiningView)
   conteiningView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
   conteiningView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
   conteiningView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant:  -8).isActive = true
   conteiningView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: (width/16*9)*2).isActive = true // twice of the blue view 
   conteiningView.layoutIfNeeded()

   self.conteiningView.addSubview(topView)
   topView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: conteiningView.topAnchor).isActive = true
   topView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: conteiningView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
   topView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: conteiningView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
   topView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width/16*9).isActive = true // 16:9 ration 


   conteiningView.addSubview(userImage)
   userImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: conteiningView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
   userImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: conteiningView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
   userImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width/2).isActive = true
   userImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width/2).isActive = true
   userImage.layer.cornerRadius = width/4 // to mantain nice proportions 

   conteiningView.addSubview(userNameLabel)
   userNameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userImage.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
   userNameLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userImage.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
   userNameLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
   userNameLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
   ```

With red background:

[image]
With clear background:

[image]

**UPDATE: The answer above works but I have actually found the problem:**

1. Even if I had set:

   ```
   self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
   self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300
   ```
2. For some (silly me) I had also implemented:

   ```
   tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
   ```

This, of course, does not be implemented for the automatic dimension to work.

3. removing that allowed to use the following code to achieve the same result but without setting a predefined height:

   ```
      self.addSubview(conteiningView)
      conteiningView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
      conteiningView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
      conteiningView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant:  -8).isActive = true
      conteiningView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
      conteiningView.layoutIfNeeded()

      self.conteiningView.addSubview(topView)
      topView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:     conteiningView.topAnchor).isActive = true
      topView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: conteiningView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
      topView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: conteiningView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
      topView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width/16*9).isActive = true

      conteiningView.addSubview(userImage)
      userImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true // the vertical center is now set nicely at bottom edge of my top view. 
      userImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
      userImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width/2).isActive = true
      userImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width/2).isActive = true
       userImage.layer.cornerRadius = width/4

      conteiningView.addSubview(userNameLabel)
      userNameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userImage.bottomAnchor, constant: 2).isActive = true
      userNameLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userImage.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
      userNameLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
      userNameLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true
   ```